# setters and getters with heavily nested composition

Tags: c++, composition, getter-setter

I study the dynamics of multibody systems and am trying to apply OO techniques to my work in modelling various mechanical systems.  One thing I am encountering in my work is that I it makes sense to create several building block classes that are used as private member variables in higher level classes that represent more complicated systems.

What I'm struggling with is that a common task is in numerical analysis is parameter analysis -- essentially looking at how the behavior of a system changes as you vary it's parameters.  With the hierarchical nesting imposed by composition, what is the best way to allow for fine grain control of the parameters in the private member variables that comprise a more complicated object?  Returning a reference I know is frowned but the only other alternative I see is to either reconstruct the high level objects repeatedly or to provide a lot of wrapper setters/accessors which set/get the private member data (and perhaps have some logic to ensure data integrity).

Here is a typical example:

```
template <typename T>
class fooA {
  public:
   /* setters, getters, etc... */
  private:
    T w,x,y,z;
};
template <typename T>
class fooB {
  public:
  /* setters, getters, etc... and maybe ways to set/get private members of type class A */
  private:
 T d, e, f, g, h;
 fooA<T> i, j, k;
 };
```

What would be the best (or preferred) way to adjust the w, x, y, z, data of the private i, j, k members of the fooB class?  Write setters/getters in the fooB class, or return a reference, or something else?  A common use case in my application is to want to do a parameter on the w, x, y, z quantities of the i member of a fooB instance.

EDIT:
The object I am modelling is a bicycle, which I describe with a total of 31 parameters.  30 of those parameters have a front and rear analog, so I chose to make a class to represent those 15 parameters, then have the bicycle class have two of these as private member variables.  11 of those 15 parameters can be grouped into a set of parameters which can makes sense to into its own class, so again, I group those into a class and make it a private member of the class with 15 parameters.  And within that class, 6 of those 11 parameters can further be lumped into their own class.  So, I have essentially four levels of nesting.  So, if a client of the highest level bicycle class wants to adjust one of the parameters in the lowest level (which is a typical use case in my application), they can:

- construct a whole new object, passing the new parameter in the constructor
- I can provide setters / getters at some level of granularity, perhaps all the way down to the lowest level.  If I provide setters at the smallest level of granularity, my high level class becomes a bit of mess, and as has been mentioned by many posts, this is probably not a good design.  But I'm not sure how to allow the access otherwise.

Perhaps I should flatten the hierarchy and make all of the various classes I mentioned into member variables of the top level bicycle class, rather than nesting them so much?  This would result in more member variables of the bicycle class, but less nesting, and would make the writing of the setter/getter for the bike class more straightforward.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why is returning a reference a problem? As long as you know what you're doing, this should not be a problem. You could make operator= of fooA private if you do not need it, to ensure assignment to a getter is impossible.

Comment: @RuudvA, Returning a reference to say, the i member of a fooB instance, is a problem when i, j, k, d, e, f, g, h, need to be validated anytime one of them changes.   By this I mean that even if i, j, k are consistent on their own, there may be additional constraints in the class fooA that need to be satisfied -- so i, j, k can't be set to arbitrary (yet consistent in an isolated case) things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usual" way of doing this, at least in the places I've worked, has
been to use setters and getters along the lines of:

```
class A
{
    T myX;
public:
    T x() const { return myX; }
    void x( T const& newX ) { myX = newX; }
};
```

Generally, however, too many setters and getters is a sign of poor 
design.  In this case, if I understand you correctly, your class has a
set of members which can be characterized as "parameters", which affect
how it does its job, but which are defined by, and may be modified by,
the user of the class.  In this case, I'd suggest creating a component
to represent them; since this is pure data (no behavior), a `struct`
would seem more appropriate.  In this case, you'd have a single setter
and getter.  Or a single function returning a reference to the
parameters.  In this case, I think that returning a reference would be
quite appropriate; the fact that you've regrouped everything that client
code can modify in a separate entity, with a semantically significant
type name, is sufficient to make the overall logic clear.

Comment: see my EDIT above.  My system has 31 parameters that a typical user may want to adjust.

Comment: @hazelnusse Then you'll definitely want to regroup them into a structure.  You don't want 31 getters and setters.  (Your approach of defining subgroups makes a lot of sense.  But I think I'd still group all of the subgroups into a single parameters type.)  Alternatively, let the (sub-)groups take care of any consistency checking, and simply have a function which returns a non-const reference to the parameters.  (I slightly favor the setter method, which requires the client to create a complete new object each time, possibly be modifying an object obtained by the getter. But both are valid.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check integrity every time w, x, y or z changes, then you have to use setters. Anything else would create a loophole for a value changing without being validated.

It seems that you are reluctant to write getters/setters for some reason, but that's pretty standard OO technique.

Comment: actually, getters/setters have nothing to do with OO.  OO is about objects interacting by letting objects do something.  getters/setters is about querying/manipulating objects.  They may be convenient or even make sense, but they're not OO.

Comment: Too many getters and setters is a sign of poor OO design.  If integrity is an issue, it would make more sense if the parameters were regrouped in a single object, which can be set with a single function call.  Otherwise, if the integrity involves relationships between the values (e.g. y must be less than w), you impose integrity on all of the intermediate states when a client wants to change several values.

Comment: @stefaanv, setters and getters are a way to maintain encapsulation, while providing a way to modify an object. They don't need to correspond to a field and can have side effects, such as validation. They are a standard technique in all OO languages, with some - like C# - supporting them directly.

Comment: @JamesKanze, the class in this case is already grouping the parameters. If all parameters always changed together, then what you suggest would make sense, but if a parameter can change independently, then you need a setter for it. Maybe validation is not a good word in this case - what if changing one parameter required adjusting the others automatically. At that point you are arguing the semantics of whether a function that takes a new value for a parameter should be called a setter or simply a member function.

Comment: Too many setters and getters are a sign of poor OO design.  OO is concerned with behavior, not attribute values.  And as I understand his question, his class isn't grouping the parameters; the abstraction of the class isn't to be a set of parameters, but to do something using a set of parameters.  In his case, having a setter for the parameters (globally) is probably good design; having a setter for each individual parameter, probably less so.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I'd like to be able to individually vary each parameter -- this is a typical use case in my application.  My system has 31 parameters... so grouping them as you suggest is what I have already done, but then I run into the issue of this deep nesting that makes changing one of the parameters at the lowest level a bit of a mess.  Thoughts?

Comment: @hazelnusse Two solutions: client code does a get, modifies the object, then set; or you provide a function returning a reference to the contained object.  In either case, client can modify what he wants, subject to any constraints you've built into the parameter types.  And in such cases, where the object is pure data, don't be afraid of a C style `struct`, with all data members public (for the parameters, I mean).

Comment: @JamesKanze, I disagree on the reference approach for the same reasons as before (no encapsulation). But perhaps this is pointing out the problem with this question - hazelnusse, you already know the possible answers, but you are asking for opinions on OO design. One of the other forums, like Programming, might be a better place for this.

Comment: @lucas1024 Whether the reference looses essential encapsulation or not depends on a lot of things; there is no dogmatically correct answer.  In his design, a `Bycyle` has parameters; the presence of this "attribute" is part of the design.  Any necessary coherence checking can and should be in the parameters class (which might in such cases have getters and setters---or might not, but I suspect that in this case, it logically would, at least at some level).  There's also the question of who does the setting---if everything is within a closed system, less checking is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For read only operations, you can always return a `const` reference. For example

```
class fooB
{
public:

    fooA<T> const & get_i() const { return i; }

...
};
```

For setting operations, you indicated that some constraints have to be maintained among the components in the composition. There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Somebody takes charge of the components in a centralized approach. In this case all setters have to go through the `fooB` class and it maintains the consistency of the (sub)system.
2. Components talk to each other. In this more complicated distributed case, components have to be aware of one another. For setting, `fooB` can return a reference to a component as it is the component's duty to send a message (i.e., call an update function) to the relevant others when the component has been `set`. Setting up the communication channels between components (e.g., observer patterns with listeners and registration) can be done by `fooB`.

Comment: Would you implement the latter approach with some sort of pub/sub & signal/slot mechanism?  There may be cases where no notification of other objects is needed because they are used in an isolated fashion, but in my nested high level class described above, they aren't isolated and need to be aware of each other in some way.

Comment: Yes you will need some form of communication mechanism, for example, a component can maintain a list of who it should contact on set. If no notification of other objects is needed, this component should not have any other component in it's contact list. Hence invoking an update will not do anything on an empty list.

How complex the communication mechanism is really depends on the problem domain. You can refer to existing mechanisms like signal/slot, observer pattern, event driven, etc.